# Phan: how to exclude several root folders with `exclude_file_regex`

Tags: php, regex, static-analysis

I have

```
phan --version
Phan 3.2.0
php-ast version 1.0.11dev
PHP version used to run Phan: 7.3.23
```

And `.phan/config.php`:

```
…

    'directory_list' => [
         '.',
         'vendor',
    ],

    "exclude_analysis_directory_list" => [
         'vendor',
        '.phan'
    ],
    'exclude_file_regex' => '@^src/@'
```

I want fully exclude (from parsing and analysis) `src` and several other my project's root subdirectories. (Long story why `src` among them, but it is)

But `phan -D` with this config prints:

```
…
Going to parse 'src/Kernel.php' (3%)
Going to parse 'src/Migrations/2019/07/Version20190714141053.php' (3%)
…
```

Why?

If I change config like this:

```
'exclude_file_regex' => '@src/@'
```

Those files seems ignored (like I want), but another problem arises: `/vendor/some-vendor/some-package/src/…` files are getting ignored too which in turn leads to false positive errors from analysis itself.

Can I somehow ignore several root subdirectories? What should I do for this?

This `@^src/@` regex is simplified version of `@^(src|subdir1|subdir2)/@` with which I've started this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered at [Phan gitter chat](https://gitter.im/phan/phan) by @TysonAndre:

> exclude_file_regex should be @(^(./)?src/)@ since it's probably checking against ./src/

### Also

See [Phan cli help](https://github.com/phan/phan/blob/master/internal/CLI-HELP.md)

> --dump-parsed-file-list
> Emit a newline-separated list of files Phan would parse to stdout.   This is useful to verify that options such as
> exclude_file_regex are   properly set up, or to run other checks on
> the files Phan would parse.